# Python - JSON TypeError: key 'tuple' is not a string

Tags: python, json, tuples

I have this `dictionary`, where `keys` are `tuples`:

```
tags = {'playlist': {('seen live', 21): 1, ('indie', 46): 1, ('british rock', 2): 1, ('alternative rock', 19): 1, ('00s', 2): 1, ('english', 2): 1, ('brit pop', 2): 1, ('pop rock', 2): 1, ('90s', 10): 1, ('classic rock', 3): 1, ('hard rock', 2): 1, ('Manchester', 4): 1, ('favorites', 1): 1, ('british', 61): 1, ('rock', 89): 1, ('alternative', 53): 1, ('punk', 1): 1, ('male vocalists', 2): 1, ('britpop', 100): 1, ('pop', 7): 1, ('UK', 4): 1, ('oasis', 9): 1, ('indie rock', 12): 1, ('Britrock', 3): 1, ('england', 1): 1, ('brit rock', 2): 1}}
```

I am trying to upload this to directory with `json` format, with:

```
with open(path, 'w') as t:
        json.dump(tags, t)
```

but it seems that `tuples` as `keys` are not allowed using `json.dump()`, because I get this traceback:

`TypeError: key ('seen live', 21) is not a string`

Is there a workaround this?

Comment: There are multiple options depending on what you want to do with the serialized data layer. Was there a reason you chose JSON in the first place? Are you passing this to non-python programs?

Comment: problable will be passing it to non-pyhton programs, yes. I chose it because music API data is usually serialized with JSON, and I'll be processing that kind of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the data as JSON you need to convert it into a form JSON can use. I have no idea what your data is or whether this is the best option, but as an example I convert the tuple into a string that can be split out later. So, for instance, `('alternative rock', 19)` becomes `'alternative rock 19'`. You may want some other format, but this is one reasonable way to do it.

```
>>> tags = {'playlist': {('seen live', 21): 1, ('indie', 46): 1, ('british rock', 2): 1, ('alternative rock', 19): 1, ('00s', 2): 1, ('english', 2): 1, ('brit pop', 2): 1, ('pop rock', 2): 1, ('90s', 10): 1, ('classic rock', 3): 1, ('hard rock', 2): 1, ('Manchester', 4): 1, ('favorites', 1): 1, ('british', 61): 1, ('rock', 89): 1, ('alternative', 53): 1, ('punk', 1): 1, ('male vocalists', 2): 1, ('britpop', 100): 1, ('pop', 7): 1, ('UK', 4): 1, ('oasis', 9): 1, ('indie rock', 12): 1, ('Britrock', 3): 1, ('england', 1): 1, ('brit rock', 2): 1}}
>>> tags['playlist'] = {'{} {}'.format(*k):v for k,v in tags['playlist'].items()}
>>> print(tags['playlist'])
{'alternative 53': 1, 'oasis 9': 1, 'alternative rock 19': 1, 'british 61': 1, 'male vocalists 2': 1, 'brit rock 2': 1, 'england 1': 1, 'punk 1': 1, 'pop rock 2': 1, '00s 2': 1, 'seen live 21': 1, 'indie 46': 1, 'hard rock 2': 1, 'favorites 1': 1, 'Britrock 3': 1, 'english 2': 1, 'indie rock 12': 1, '90s 10': 1, 'classic rock 3': 1, 'brit pop 2': 1, 'pop 7': 1, 'british rock 2': 1, 'rock 89': 1, 'UK 4': 1, 'Manchester 4': 1, 'britpop 100': 1}
>>> json.dumps(tags)
'{"playlist": {"alternative 53": 1, "oasis 9": 1, "alternative rock 19": 1, "british 61": 1, "male vocalists 2": 1, "brit rock 2": 1, "england 1": 1, "punk 1": 1, "pop rock 2": 1, "00s 2": 1, "seen live 21": 1, "indie 46": 1, "hard rock 2": 1, "favorites 1": 1, "Britrock 3": 1, "english 2": 1, "indie rock 12": 1, "90s 10": 1, "classic rock 3": 1, "brit pop 2": 1, "pop 7": 1, "british rock 2": 1, "rock 89": 1, "UK 4": 1, "Manchester 4": 1, "britpop 100": 1}}'
```

Comment: You could use something like `repr` to give a string representation of the tuple. However that brings in  the problem of how to parse it back without `eval`

Answer (score 1):

If you need support for more diverse datatypes, use the `pickle` module instead.

```
import pickle

with open(path, 'w') as t:
    pickle.dump(tags, t)
```

Comment: Perhaps.. it all depends on what other software wants to read it. pickle only works for python programs.